# Drag and Drop is not triggering in safari browser in browser stack

Tags: protractor, browserstack

Code used:
1st Iteration:

```
line1. Functions.highlightelement(vertical_slider); //highlights the given xpath value
line2. browser.actions().dragAndDrop(vertical_slider,{x:0, y:-250}).perform(); // drag till certain position.
```

Error message in browser stack:

> Failed: An invalid command argument was specified: Node handle not
> provided for 'Element' origin. It fails after clickandhold and mouse
> move.

```
2nd Iteration:
line1. Functions.highlightelement(vertical_slider); //highlights the given xpath value
line2. vertical_slider.click(); // click on the thumb element
line3. browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_UP).perform();
```

Error message returned from browser stack server:

> Failed: The command 'POST
> /session/7b14db2742b2b103dbbff0756957d2377c35f513/keys' was not found.

3rd iteration:

```
line1. Functions.highlightelement(vertical_slider); //highlights the given xpath value
line2. vertical_slider.click(); // click on the thumb element
line3. browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.chord(protractor.Key.CONTROL,'end'));
```

Error returned from browser stack server:

> Failed: The command 'POST
> /session/7b14db2742b2b103dbbff0756957d2377c35f513/keys' was not found.

However it works well in Chrome Browser (OS x , WINDOWS) , MS EDGE browser (WINDOWS).

Any help on this.

Comment: You should format your code to help readibility. Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is caused by [JsonWireProtocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#command-summary) commands being sent to a session initiated in the [W3C WebDriver protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#endpoints).

You can use the browserstack capability [browserstack.use_w3c](https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities) to explicitly set the protocol to be used.

Answer (score 0):

unlikely to solve the problem, but worth a try. I use this function

```
     /**
     * Drags first element to the second one
     * @param    {ElementFinder}        $element
     * @param    {(ElementFinder|{x: number, y: number})}       $destination
     * @returns  {promise.Promise}
     */
    dragAndDrop: ($element, $destination) => {
        return browser
            .actions()
            .mouseMove($element)
            .perform()
            .then(() =>
                browser
                    .actions()
                    .mouseDown($element)
                    .perform()
            )
            .then(() =>
                browser
                    .actions()
                    .mouseMove($destination)
                    .perform()
            )
            .then(() =>
                browser
                    .actions()
                    .mouseUp()
                    .perform()
            );
    }
```

just don't forget to `await` it

```
await dragAndDrop(vertical_slider,{x:0, y:-250})
```